# Why does Terminal.app ignore my cursor preferences?

Tags: terminal, preferences

I recently did a fresh install of macOS Monterey (previously was using Big Sur), and now I notice that the cursor always blinks in Terminal.app. I'm aware of these preferences:

[image: Terminal cursor preferences]

but no matter what I put here, I always get a blinking block. For example, if I set the preferences in the image above, which say to use a vertical bar, and then double-click the profile name to open a new window with that profile I still get a block:

[image: Block cursor]

It's not like *all* of the preferences are ignored. If I change the font on the same window and then follow the same process to open a new window, it works:

[image: Comic Sans prompt]

This happens even after starting over from scratch using `defaults delete com.apple.Terminal`.

What's going on here? **How can I make Terminal.app honor my cursor preferences?** Is it possible that some other configuration, for example in the shell (I use fish) overrides the cursor settings?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Cursor properties are profile-dependent, just to be sure: could it be that the window uses a different profile than the one you are configuring? Could you try exporting the profile (open Preferences > Profile, select the profile, press the "more actions" icon next to the minus sign, then select Export...), deleting it in Terminal and then importing it? It would probably help if you could share the exported profile with Google Drive or similar. By the way, the cursor setting is defined after this line `<key>CursorType</key>` and looks like this: `<integer>0</integer>`.

Comment: It's might be worth to look into .inputrc

Comment: Thanks @jaume, but this happens even with the stock profiles, even after deleting all Terminal preferences (see `defaults` command in the question). I'm sure I'm editing the right profile because font changes _do_ take effect.

Comment: @AivarPaalberg can you say more about what you mean? I don't think I have an `.inputrc` file.

Comment: There are many ways how one can set up his computer. In my .inputrc I have set keymap to vi-command, also made visible vim mode on prompt and set different cursors for normal (block) and insert mode (vertical bar). Result of such setup is that in Terminal preferences I can change the color of cursor but not cursor shape - or more specifically I can change the shape but this have no effect (something similar to your problem description). In my case this is expected behaviour.